# Reading in data that contains \n using R software

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose I have a string

```
"1|2|3|4|5|6 
7|8|9"
```

Note the '\n' present after 6

```
scan(text="1|2|3|4|5|6 
7|8|9", sep="|",what="")
```

would return you:

```
Read 9 items
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6 " "7"  "8"  "9"
```

how can I get 8 items where the 6th item should be `6 \n7` instead of two seperate items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
strsplit(paste(scan(text="1|2|3|4|5|6
+ 7|8|9", sep="\n", what="character"), collapse="\n"), "\\|")
```